# is $GL(n,\mathbb R)$ dense in $M(n,\mathbb R)$

Tags: metric-spaces

Is $GL(n,\mathbb R)$ dense in $M(n,\mathbb R)$? I have proved it to be open,not closed,not connected but not sure about this property .How to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hint: A matrix has finitely many eigenvalues.  If none of them is $0$, ...

Comment: Sorry I did not get it

Comment: Add a small multiple of $I$ to your matrix, and it becomes invertible.

Comment: How to prove that

Comment: Eigenvalues of $A + \epsilon I$ are (eigenvalues of $A$) $+ \epsilon$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael where did you use "none of them are zero"(eigen values)? what if something is zero

Comment: @CloudJR If an eigenvalue is $0$, the matrix is not in $GL(n,\mathbb R)$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael what is the metric used in this problem? I break my head for an hour please help!

Comment: @CloudJR Use the Euclidean metric on $M(n,\mathbb R)$, identified as $\mathbb R^{n^2}$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael then why people are talking about determinant? To check it is invertible?

Answer (score 17):

Yes, $GL(n,\mathbb R)$ is dense in $M(n,\mathbb R)$.

Using the determinant function $\det:M(n,\mathbb R)\rightarrow \mathbb R$, check that for small values of $\varepsilon$, the matrix $A+\varepsilon I_n$ is invertible.

Comment: Is $A+nB$ invertible for any n if A and B invertible?

Comment: $n$ is quite a big number....

Comment: No, not in general. It is true for only finitely many values of $n$. Notice that $\varepsilon \mapsto \det(A+\varepsilon I_n)$ is actually a polynomial function.

Comment: How to check that $A+\epsilon B$ is invertible .Any hints@Bebop

Comment: The function $\varepsilon \mapsto \det(A+\varepsilon B)$ vanishes at most $n$ times since it is a real polynomial function. Hence, there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that for any $p\geq N$, $\det(A+\frac{1}{p}B)\neq 0$ i.e. $A+\frac{1}{p}B$ is invertible.

Answer (score 7):

Since this is posted under the tag metric spaces, I will show that the statement is not true for every metric:

Let $d$ be the discrete metric:
$$
d(A,B) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{ if } A=B\\ 1 & \text{ if } A\ne B.\end{cases}
$$
Then
$$
d(0,B) =1
$$
for all invertible $B$, hence $GL(n,\mathbb R)$ is not dense in $M(n,\mathbb R)$.

If the metric is induced by a norm, $d(A,B)=\|A-B\|$,  then the statement is true. Let $A$ be not invertible. Then there are invertible matrices $S,T$ such that
$$
SAT = \pmatrix{ I_r & 0 \\ 0 & 0 },
$$
with $r=rank(A)$. Now let $\epsilon\ne0$ be given.
Set
$$
A_\epsilon :=  S^{-1} \pmatrix{ (1+\epsilon)I_r & 0 \\ 0 & \epsilon I_{n-r} } T^{-1} = A + \epsilon S^{-1}T^{-1}.
$$
This matrix is clearly invertible as a product of invertible matrices $S^{-1}$, $\pmatrix{ (1+\epsilon)I_r & 0 \\ 0 & \epsilon I_{n-r} }$, $T^{-1}$.
Then
$$
A-A_\epsilon = S^{-1}\pmatrix{ -\epsilon I_r & 0 \\ 0 & -\epsilon I_{n-r}} T^{-1} = - \epsilon S^{-1}T^{-1},
$$
which shows
$$
\|A-A_\epsilon\| = |\epsilon|\cdot \|S^{-1}T^{-1}\|.
$$
And $GL(n,\mathbb R)$ is dense in $M(n,\mathbb R)$.

Answer (score 2):

The way I like writing this is as follows: Consider $A\in M_{n}(\mathbb R)$ and let $\varepsilon>0$. Let $\lambda _1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues of $A$. Take $\delta$ such that $0<\delta<\frac{\varepsilon}{n^{1/2}}$ and $\delta\neq \lambda_j$ for every  $j\in \{1, \ldots, n\}$. Define

$$A_\delta:=A-\delta I.$$
Then $A_\delta$ is invertible. In fact, on the contrary,

$$\det(A_\delta)=\det(A-\delta I)=0$$

and therefore $\delta$ would be an eigenvalue of $A$, so that $\delta =\lambda_j$ for some $j\in \{1, \ldots, n\}$. This contradicts the choice of $\delta$. Finally,

$$d_2(A, A_\delta)=\|A-A_\delta\|_2=\|A-(A-\delta I)\|_2=|\delta|\|I\|_2=\delta {n^{1/2}}<\frac{\varepsilon}{n^{1/2}} n^{1/2}=\varepsilon.$$

I assumed here that your metric is induced by norm:

$$\|A\|_2=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}^2\right)^{1/2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Here GLn(R) is subspace as a metric space in set of all metrices of order n. If I take any member in Mn(R): if it is in GLn(R) then clearly we get sequence of GLn(R) that converge to our chosen point. Now if it is not in GLn(R) then by changing exactly one element of the matrix I can make it a member of the set of all invertible matrices, so by this way I can get a sequence of GLn(R) which converges to set of our chosen point.